# Wordpress admin_menu capability

Tags: wordpress

I'm having problems with a menu page. I have setup

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'todays_orders_page'); 

function todays_orders_page() {
add_menu_page('Todays orders', 'Todays orders', 'todays_orders', __FILE__,'todays_orders');
}
```

However, visiting the page with a user who has "todays_orders" only capability results in a permission denied error.

Any help would be great.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: You are missing the menu slug (where `_FILE_` is).

Answer (score 0):

The arguments that you are passing to [`add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) are not correct - you are omitting the "capability" and not passing in a page function. Try the following (this example uses the [`edit_posts` capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)). You should replace "page_function" with the function that is used to display the page contents.

```
add_menu_page( "Today's orders", "Today's orders", 'todays_orders', 'edit_posts', 'page_function' );
```